# Publish a SharePoint 2013 Provider Hosted app (customer local IIS) to the SharePoint App Store?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Can a SharePoint 2013 Provider Hosted app - that will use an accopanying, on premises at customer deployed IIS Web Site - be published to the SharePoint App Store, or can an app of this kind only be distributed "manually"?

Elaboration on what is meant by "manually":

Is the customer required to either:

- Download and deploy Web Application to act as provider hosted component
- Acquire and deploy Web Application to act as provider hosted component, directly from the reseller (incl. consultant assistance)

Answer (score 1):

Provider hosted app can be publish to the SharePoint app store. You just need to publish the `.app` file to the Seller dashboard while publishing. And the WebApplication to the Server where you want to publish.

Before publishing .app file to Store you need to successfully deploy the web application to the server and change the path of the `<StartPage>` in `AppManifest.xml` file to
`https://severpath/pages/yourPage.aspx`

Thus you can publish your Provider Hosted app to the App Store.

Comment: I am aware of the option to host the remote web on a shared server - however, the question was regarding "(..) on premises at customer deployed IIS Web Site (..)".